# C# check if selected items in a listbox are in a sequence

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listbox, selection

I have a listbox that contains 29 items, I want to check if the user selected the items in a sequence such as if he chooses (1,2,3,4) a messagebox will show up saying he chose (1 to 4) and if he chooses (1,3,5) the messagebox will say he chose (1,3 and 5).

Comment: Did you tried something? Or you are expecting somebody will do your job ;) If you tried something can you describe more specific issue where you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I see what you want to do. The first approach would be to **know what he selected** like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
{
  MessageBox.Show("You selected the item " + listBox1.SelectedItems[i] + " with index " + i.ToString());
}
```

And then, as saw in the MessageBox, **get the index** which I think is what you want.
If you want to list **all selected items in one MessageBox**, just let the user select the items he want, make a button that will say what items he selected **in total**.